# Как обновить HttpPost?

Tags: java, android

Имею такой код:

```
                HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(SERVERURI + "site.php");
                List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(2);
                nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("login", "Login"));
                nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("password", "Password"));
                httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs, "UTF-8"));

                // Execute HTTP Post Request
                HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
                if (response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode() == 200) {
                    HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
```

Все работает, но очень не нравиться то что половину тут зачеркивает (deprecated). Как можно это исправить? (обновить)

Comment: Однажды великий мудрец сказал: "Работает - не трогай." (c)

Comment: @iFr0z, Вы с таким подходом к делу, дaлеко не уедете.

Comment: @EdgarAsatryan дОлеко не уеду, а вот дАлеко может быть) P.S. шутка-минутка

Comment: @iFr0z, спасибо, не заметил.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Класс `DefaultHttpClient` помечен как устаревший. Из оффицальной [документации](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/httpclient/apidocs/org/apache/http/impl/client/DefaultHttpClient.html) Apache

> Deprecated.  (4.3) use HttpClientBuilder see also CloseableHttpClient.

[Здесь](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15336477/deprecated-java-httpclient-how-hard-can-it-be), можно посмотреть как "обновить".

---

Оффициальная [документация](https://developer.android.com/reference/org/apache/http/impl/client/DefaultHttpClient.html) Android рекомендует использовать [`HttpURLConnection`](https://developer.android.com/reference/javax/net/ssl/HttpsURLConnection.html).

Если решитесь мигрировать на `HttpsURLConnection`, то скорее всего вам понадобится [`AsyncTask`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html), а использование этой связки *может* привести к очень большому и избыточному коду.

---

Можете использовать более высокоруовневые библиотеки, например

[Android Asynchronous Http Client](http://loopj.com/android-async-http/)

```
dependencies {
    compile 'com.loopj.android:android-async-http:1.4.8'
}
```

**UPD 16.09.2016**

Более изящный HTTP клиент [Retrofit](http://square.github.io/retrofit/)

```
dependencies {
    compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.1.0'
    compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.0.2'
    compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.6.1'
}
```